# iOS BLE app stops scanning in background after only minutes

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

## What I need to do:

My iOS app needs to be able to scan in the background (even when device is locked) and connect to advertising peripherals. I would like the app to be scanning even days or weeks into the future.

*I understand that in the end, there is no guarantee that I will get what I want, but I want to be sure that I am following the best practices.*

## My current setup:

I begin scanning in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.services options:nil];
```

`self.services` is a list of services that I am expecting. I also make this call in `centralManagerDidUpdateState`:

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
  
  switch ([central state]) {
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
      [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.services options:nil];
    ...
  }
}
```

Finally, I scan for peripherals when a connected peripheral disconnects. The peripheral that I am using disconnects to conserve battery, so it actually happen pretty quickly. Given the needs of my project, I can't redesign the device to stay connected. It wakes up and advertises when it has new data to send, so it's fairly unpredictable.

## My question:

Is there something I can differently so that the app will scan in a background and locked state for longer periods of time?